# Index dimension must be <= 2 when adding to a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add a new column to a DataFrame using Pandas. Although I keep getting an error. Here is my code:

```
classes = pd.DataFrame(data['class'])
df['class'] = classes
```

And every time I run this I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\gjohn\Documents\code\machineLearning\trading_bot\filter.py", line 147, in <module>
    df['class'] = list(classes)
  File "C:\Users\gjohn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_index.py", line 76, in __setitem__
    row, col = self._validate_indices(key)
  File "C:\Users\gjohn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_index.py", line 138, in _validate_indices
    row = self._asindices(row, M)
  File "C:\Users\gjohn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_index.py", line 162, in _asindices
    raise IndexError('Index dimension must be <= 2')
IndexError: Index dimension must be <= 2
```

Why am I getting this?

Comment: You may need to check the index of classes

Comment: What do you mean? Classes is just a column filled with either 1s or 0s.

Comment: can you show  a sample of classes or the dataframe itself

Comment: How do you want me to show it? It is just like the following:
Review | Coin | Class:
"It was great" | "Florida" | 1